# What is the meaning of "If the way Thou choosest, Lead to pain and loss"?

Tags: meaning, archaicisms

What is the meaning of "If the way Thou **choosest**, Lead to pain and loss"? How would you put it in modern English?

It is a verse from Margaret E. Barber's song "The Path I Travel." The whole context is:

> If the path I travel Lead me to the Cross, 
>   If the way Thou choosest, Lead to pain and loss, 
>   Let the compensation Daily, hourly, be 
>   Shadowless communion, Blessed Lord with Thee.

Comment: You might have better luck over on Christianity.stackexchange. There's a whole lot of Christian theology wrapped up in this passage.

Comment: @T.E.D. The question isn't about Christianity *per se*, but about English from an earlier time. Christianity is only incidental to the question.

Comment: @zpletan - Only in the very basics. To **really** explain the sentence, you'd have to get into why Thou is capitalized and what that implies, the Christian conception of what "way" means (John 14:6, among other things), why a Christian would consdier this a huge sacrifice, etc. I started to write an answer with all this, and halfway through realized that it doesn't really belong here, and folks over there could probably do a much better answer than I.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means

> If the way You (God) chooses (for the author) leads to pain and loss

Comment: With an interesting, but now dated, use of subjunctive 'lead' in the first and second lines.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that "choosest" is an ancient way to express the past, so I would translate it as "chose" (IInd voice of the paradigm) in modern English.
So the construction probably is:
"If the way You chose, led to pain and loss".

Comment: -1 -est is an older suffix for second-person verbs, not for past tense

Comment: I choose, thou choosest, he chooseth ... present tense.  Past tense: I chose, ???

Comment: Past tense: I chose, Thou chosest, he chose (I think).